# How can i install mysql_config on Red Hat Linux 4?

Tags: linux, mysql, redhat, rpm

I've been tasked with implementing a few upgrades on a Red Hat Linux 4 box that is already running MySQL.  I've found the need for the mysql_config tool, but i can't locate it as already being installed anywhere.

**The package manager i'm using is RPM**.

```
rpm -qa | grep -i mysql 
MySQL-client-enterprise-gpl-5.0.56sp1-0.rhel4
MySQL-shared-compat-enterprise-gpl-5.0.56sp1-0.rhel4
MySQL-server-enterprise-gpl-5.0.56sp1-0.rhel4
```

Here's some info about the MySQL installation:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%version%';
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                         |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
| protocol_version        | 10                            |
| version                 | 5.0.56sp1-enterprise-gpl-log  |
| version_comment         | MySQL Enterprise Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | i686                          |
| version_compile_os      | redhat-linux-gnu              |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

I've done a bit of looking around online, but not having much luck.

How can i install mysql_config on this box?

Comment: 4? Isn't that way out of support?

Comment: Indeed :(.  My pleas for upgrade have been heard, and the wheels of IT beauracracy are moving, but slowly, and i need to move forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `mysql_config` is a developer tool, it will probably be in the equivalent `devel` package. You seem to have obtained these packages directly from Oracle, so ask Oracle to provide you with the equivalent `MySQL-devel-enterprise-gpl` package.

(Oh, and that's about 40 patches out of date; it's on 5.0.96 now.)

(And RHEL 4 went out of support two years ago...)